# jquery select2 multiple selection,show search and infinite load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I have a dropdown that loads data from database ( having records 20,000 + ). I followed http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623566/Select2-The-Ultimate-jQuery-Autocomplete to load data on demand. But it allows only single selection. So I made an edit by adding "multiple: true" but this will hide the search box.

```
 $('#attendee').select2(
 {
      placeholder: 'Enter name',
      //Does the user have to enter any data before sending the ajax request
      minimumInputLength: 0,            
      allowClear: true,
      multiple: true
 }
```

So is there a way I can do multiple selection, show search box and have infinite scroll ( i.e. load data on demand on scroll)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try multiple-select for multi select drop down list. You can also use filter for searching text.

[Multiple Select](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/)

You can get demo and script in above link. Hope this help.

Comment: For select2 plugin only search functionality worked with ajax load,multiple select. Bit search box was missing which was taken care with css changes